# how to solve target sum question with vector<string> return type?

Tags: c++, recursion, vector

Write a recursive function which returns the subsets of the array which sum
to target. Return type of function should be Vector.
Print the value returned.

...code....

```
vector<string> targetsum(vector<int>& array, int idx, int target)
{
    if (target == 0)
    {
        vector<string> base;
        base.push_back("");
        cout << "base";
        return base;
    }

    vector<string> myans;

    for (int i = idx; i < array.size(); i++)
    {
        if (target - array[i] >= 0)
        {
            myans = targetsum(array, i + 1, target - array[i]);
            myans.push_back(to_string(array[i]));
        }
    }
    return myans;
}
```

**for example**

```
Input:
5 // array size
1 3 5 7 0 // array
6 // target
output
[1 5 , 1 5 0 ]
```

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis , never asked you to do so :). BTW i tried solving the problem rather than just asking for solution.

Comment: What is wrong with the code? It always helps, if we don't have to find out ourselfs ;) The `if (target == 0)`-block seems a bit strange. What is it supposed to do and why does it not just return an empty vector (`return {}`)?

Comment: @lakshaymalhotra the way you asked indicated so, but if not, I apologize anyway.

Comment: @churill , whenever i hit target==0 , it must return an vector so that later on i can push back those values which made me reach my target .

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis , never mind bro ;) . Any insights on the question ?

Comment: Write the recursive function with the return type and parameters that are ideal. Then write a wrapper function of the form `vector<string> targetsum(vector<int>& array, int idx, int target)` that calls your version and converts your result to `vector<string>`